# Social Icons and Download Badges in mailer header?

Tags: buttons, layout, email, download, newsletter

Im currently doing a mailer design.

I've placed the social icons in the header, next to the company logo.
Underneath the social links I have put download badges, before the main content of the mailer.

[image]

Some people said that they click the download badges more than anything else in the mailer. So in a way they are the main call to action of the mailer, which is why I put them on top. My issues are that nobody has done this before and it looks weird.

I don't have enough data to defend my design, and am not sure if it's a good idea.

What do you guys think ?

Comment: Can you provide some image of the interface? We cannot decide how to answer you by guessing.

Comment: here's the image :) http://postimg.org/image/ldq8yp5e5/ so basically, this is the study of the header that they've wanted make me to do. I strongly disagree cause it's a bit overwhelming now on top

Answer (score 1):

What are the goals you want to achieve with the mailing?

I assume

1. User should read the content and click some call to action - you expect most value from it
2. If User doesn't care that much about the content, maybe at least they will download the app... Think what would be incentive if 1 is not compelling
3. If User didn't read the content, didn't downloaded the app, maybe User knows someone that could make use of it? Then share could be used.

...and this is information hierarchy that should drive the design. Order those elements through the goals.

Comment: true... hmm.. ok will take note of this! thanks man! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yeah definitely too much information there. You have two options:

1) Decide which is more important social links or download links and leave only one of those in the header.

2) Use smaller download icons for Appstore and Google play and try to use less number of social icons:

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes.. true. but for the download badges, we can't have it like that, as the apple already contacted us regarding the branding guidelines of them. So its either using the badges that I've shown above or the blue "app store" icon.

Comment: Well, then place the big download icons in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid placing external links in the header. Users have been conditioned to look for and click social links. If the mailer contains vital information it will be missed by users clicking straight into the social icons in the header. I would place social links within the footer. Its not a guarantee they will read the mailer but at least you have attempted to pursuade the user to read the information before allowing them to leave the mailer. Otherwise the mailer exsits only to provide a link to social media. Does that help?